# SQL Server Ports

Tags: sql-server-express, firewall

We recently installed a sonic firewall on our network. We have a SQL 2005 express server that's configured to listen on dynamic ports. In its configuration manager the dynamic port number is set as 1067 with its default port still 1433.

From my understanding we need to have the following ports open for it to work:

> Tcp 1433
>
> Tcp 1067
>
> Udp 1434

Problem is we still cannot connect to the server from outside. When we switch off/disconnect the firewall we can can access the server.

This tells me that the SQL server's setup is fine and the that the problem must be some port we are missing on the firewall.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue netstat -an from an MS-DOS command and try to find what are all ports opend as given in the artilce at

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

and configuring SQL 2005 to allow connections at

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

these may help according those articles:

Client-Server Communication Over a Firewall
Setting up a client to communicate to a SQL Server over a firewall is a simple three-step process:

Make SQL Server listen on a specific port on TCP (the default is 1433) or RPC (the default is a random port greater than 1023). You have to cycle the server after this change. 
Configure your firewall server to allow traffic on the specific .

Make the client (on the other side of firewall) use the appropriate connection string to talk to the  on the server. You can also use the Client Configuration Utility to add an "Advanced" entry with the appropriate Net-Library and connection string.